# What mechanisms prevent me from "ptraceing" a signed OSX application?

Tags: macos, debugging

I want to debug an application I have installed on my Mac.

The application comes in a ".app" format, which is basically a folder including the binary and some other frameworks and resources.

I was trying to attach to the process using `ptrace()`, but it seems that I get blocked by doing so (even while running as root).

This is the error I get:

```
ptrace: Cannot attach: Invalid argument ERRNO: 22 (EINVAL)
```

I *am* able to debug other apps (which I compiled myself).

I was wondering what mechanism is stopping me from doing so, and, is there is any way to bypass it.

Thanks!

Comment: What message `ptrace` gives you when trying to attach to the process?

Comment: `ptrace: Cannot attach: Invalid argument ERRNO: 22 (EINVAL)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably start with trying to debug the application with lldb to determine why you can't attach to the process.

## System Integrity Protection

If an application is signed with the [Hardened Runtime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/hardened_runtime) option, or is signed with Apple's own certificate (as Apple's official software is), [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) (in the kernel) will prevent you from debugging the application.

If you tried to run such an application under LLDB you would see one of these error (not 100% sure why one versus the other appears):

> error: process exited with status -1 (Error 1)

> error: process exited with status -1 (cannot attach to process due to System Integrity Protection)

To get around this you could try:

- Disabling SIP.
- Removing the code signature (`codesign --remove-signature application.app`), unless it's an arm64 binary or there are entitlements you need to keep (requiring a code signature).
- Resigning the bundle (`codesign -fs - application.app`), you may need to add/keep entitlements too in some cases.
- Modifying/breaking the signature to remove the hardened runtime flag (it should work in theory though it may be tricky to do and I haven't tried it).

## PT_DENY_ATTACH

A running process can also request that the kernel deny attempts to trace the process. If lldb shows an error like the following, that's probably what you are dealing with.

> Process 1234 exited with status = 45 (0x0000002d)

The most-common and safest way an application will do this is through the `ptrace` function call (although I've also seen it done through the `syscall` directly, which [I've written about previously](https://alexomara.com/blog/defeating-anti-debug-techniques-macos-ptrace-variants/)).

```
ptrace(PT_DENY_ATTACH, 0, 0, 0);
```

This is kernel-enforced so to get around it you would have to prevent the application from ever asking the kernel to deny attaching (either through the debugger or patching the binary). Historically there were also some kernel extensions to disable this feature, but I don't think any are still maintained.

Comment: Thanks! removing the code signature did enable me to debug the application, although now it does not run as it should, my guess is that the application explicitly checks if it is signed before it starts running, sounds like more patching to me :)